# Minimum number of swaps required to make a given anagram to another anagram

Tags: algorithm, dynamic-programming

Given two anagrams S1 and S2, we want to convert S1 anagram to S2 anagram. We need to find out minimum number of adjacency swaps required for this.

For Example: S1:CAT  and S2:ACT. Here minimum number of swaps is only 1. swap C to A to get S2.

How can we do it using Dynamic programming. Is it possible?

Answer (score 5):

One approach to obtain optimal solution is **reducing the problem to a [shortest path problem](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Shortest_path_problem)**.

In here, each vertex is one possible anagram using the given letters. An edge between two vertices (anagrams) exists if and only if you can move from the one to the other with a single swap.

Finding the shortest path from the input anagram to the desired one will give you the optimal number of paths.

Shortest path problem for unweighted graphs can be solved with [BFS](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Breadth-first_search), [bi-directional](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bidirectional_search) BFS or [A* algorithm](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/A%2a_search_algorithm).

Comment: Can we solve it without constructing entire Graph??

Comment: @vijji yes. You don't need the entire graph, you can generate it "on the fly" by building a function `next(anagram) = { all possible anagrams you can get to in one swap}`. This way you generate only the part of the graph you explore until you find the solution.

Comment: It means we are just applying brute force technique...but in a better way...

Comment: @vijji partially true. Unless you use A* algorithm, which is informed. You can use `#wrongly_placed_chars / 2` as an admissible heuristic.

Comment: How would you prevent the graph from "looping", I mean, a sequence of swaps leads you to some previous node? (yes, I know the algorithm would still work).

Comment: @chill Two possibilities: (1) Don't, the algorithm as said is still complete and optimal. (2) Use a `visited` set to save all previously discovered anagrams. Note that the default implementations of BFS and A* are already using such a set.